# Xcode FLAnimatedImage.h file not found issue while integrating IDNow SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, apple-m1

Following the machine and framework specs I am using:

1. Macbook with M1 Chip
2. Xcode 13.3.1
3. iOS 15.4
4. IDNow version 5.1.6
5. All required Pods are installed, i.e. 'AFNetworking','FLAnimatedImage', 'SocketRocket', 'Masonry', 'libPhoneNumber-iOS'

Following is the error I am receiving:

I have referred to the [documentation](https://github.com/idnow/de.idnow.ios), and having troubles in detecting one single framework, i.e. FLAnimatedImage.Framework in the project. It is there in the Pods folder but throwing an error of " FLAnimatedImage.h file not found ". I have also cleaned the build folder, gave all the required permissions, imported all the Compiler files in the Build Phase and chose to exclude armv64 architecture in the Build Settings. As per the internet search, I see there are issues with importing file in the project from certain frameworks because of the chip architecture. So far, I have tried all possible solutions that were found over the internet, nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Quit your Xcode.
- Right click on Xcode in your Doc, select: "Options" -> "Show in
  Finder".
- Right click on the Xcode.app and select "Get Info".
- Select the option "Open using Rosetta".
- Close the Info panel.
- Run this Xcode app and select a simulator, which will now also run
  under Rosetta.

This worked for me.